# Why is Eclipse Content Assist not using static imports

Tags: eclipse, content-assist

I'm trying to use JUnit and Mockito with content assist for static imports.

My Content Assist favorites lists:
`org.mockito.Mockito.*`

When I use content assist for the mock() method, the method is availble, but the import is just get a regular non-static import.  Why is this not working?

Comment: Interested in knowing this too. Sometimes happens to me with Assert imports too (but not always).

Answer (score 6):

Eclipse won't look for static imports unless you tell it to. From the Eclipse **Java Content Assist Favorites Preferences** help page:

> To see the static import proposals, make sure **Use static imports** is enabled on the **Content Assist** preference page

Admittedly, on my machine it was enabled by default.

Answer (score 1):

With the Eclipse of 8 years later (Eclipse 2019-12 (4.14.0)), two things are needed:

1. Window, Preferences, Java, Editor, Content Assist, make sure that the ckeckbox "Use static imports" is ticked.
2. ..., Content Assist, Favorites, add (if not already there) the types (e.g. `org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils`) or members (e.g. `org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils.EMPTY`) to the Favorites list, otherwise Content Assist won't propose to static-import those.

Answer (score 0):

I'm just getting started with Eclipse, but ran into this issue with the tutorial.  I spend a couple of hours trying to figure out what was wrong, when I invoked the content assist with ctrl+O, rather than using hover.  The static members were then displayed correctly.